# What's wrong with the setters or the if statement here

Tags: java, android

I have the below code, it works fine but only 1 if statement doesn't do anything, which I don't understand why my code is:

I've put (******This is the problematic if statement*****) next to the problematic if statement.

The funny thing is, in the first main if statement `if theVerb.endsWith(Ani)` it works perfect, but it doesn't work with the second main if statement `if theVerb.endsWith(Attah_att)`.

```
public void showResult (View showResultView) {
    Intent showResult;
    showResult = new Intent(this, VerbSearch.class);
    EditText getTheVerb = (findViewById(R.id.editText2));
    String theVerb = getTheVerb.getText().toString().trim();
    TextView setBenyan = findViewById(R.id.benyanText);
    TextView setZman = findViewById(R.id.zmanText);
    TextView setGuf = findViewById(R.id.gufText);
    TextView setVerb = findViewById(R.id.verbText);

    String ani = "תי";
    String attah_att = "ת";
    int numberOfletter;
    String Thesubstring = null;
    String tl = null;
    String fl = null;
    String fil = null;
//First main if statement
    if(theVerb.endsWith(ani)) {
        numberOfletter = theVerb.indexOf(ani);
        Thesubstring = theVerb.substring(0, numberOfletter);
        // Hitpael Past
        if((Thesubstring.length() == 5) && ((Thesubstring.substring(0,2).equals("הת") || Thesubstring.substring(0,2).equals("הש")
                || Thesubstring.substring(0,2).equals("הס") || Thesubstring.substring(0,2).equals("הז")
                || Thesubstring.substring(0,2).equals("הצ")))) {
            fil = theVerb.substring(4,5);
            setBenyan.setText("התפעל");
            setZman.setText("עבר");
            setGuf.setText("אני");
            setVerb.setText(theVerb.substring(0,4).concat(fil));
        }
    }


// second main if statement
    if(theVerb.endsWith(attah_att)) {
        numberOfletter = theVerb.indexOf(attah_att);
        Thesubstring = theVerb.substring(0, numberOfletter);
        // Hitpael Past  ******This is the problematic if statement*****
        if((Thesubstring.length() == 5) && ((Thesubstring.substring(0,2).equals("הת") || Thesubstring.substring(0,2).equals("הש")
                || Thesubstring.substring(0,2).equals("הס") || Thesubstring.substring(0,2).equals("הז")
                || Thesubstring.substring(0,2).equals("הצ")))) {
            fil = theVerb.substring(4,5);
            setBenyan.setText("התפעל");
            setZman.setText("עבר");
            setGuf.setText("אתה/את");
            setVerb.setText(theVerb.substring(0,4).concat(fil));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can edit it, no need to down vote. you could tell me first.

Comment: That is me telling you. The down vote is *incentive* for you to fix it, and will be removed once you do, assuming you let me know you fixed it.

Comment: Already modified it :)

Comment: You might also want to read "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)", e.g. do you really need all the `TextView` logic to show how an `if` statement "doesn't work"? --- And how can we verify your statement, when we don't even know the value of `Thesubstring` that "doesn't work"?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't do anything? Did you put a breakpoint at the if statement and watch the values of the variables?

Comment: Is it possible issue related to RTL? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left Anyway, the code is incomplete without having theVerb value explicitly defined.

Comment: @mTak Yes I tried a break point. This code is connected to a button. once the word written matches the first if statement, it works fine. once it matches the second if statement, the setText doens't work for it's case and no error or exceptions appears, I even tried to debug it but nothing :(

Comment: So you mean that the if condition is met, it executes the code inside the if block but the 5 lines inside this block do nothing?

Comment: @Pavel text direct is set to be from right to left as well    android:textDirection="rtl"

Comment: @mTak  I mean, if the word ends with the string Ani the code of the first if is working. but if the word ends with the string Attah_att nothing happens at all. Which is really strange. If I change the word again to end with the string Ani still only the first if statement works fine.

Comment: @AboelmagdMuhammad This nothing happens for a reason. None here knows the specifics of your app. My last suggestion is: put a breakpoint at the if statement, watch the variables and step line by line through the code to find what's going on

Comment: @AboelmagdMuhammad Unicode is fickle. What *looks* like the same characters may actually be different, so when debugging, look at the actual character arrays inside `String` to verify exact `char` values.

Comment: Note that you don't need to keep calling `.substring(0, 2)` it makes a new string every time you do that you immediately throw away. You can use `Thesubstring.startsWith("ס")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I finally found out what was the problem. I only needed to use `lastIndexOf` instead of `indexOf`